# Can't find monitor in python using screeninfo

Tags: python, screen

When I call the function **get_monitors()**

```
from screeninfo import get_monitors

monitors = get_monitors()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/manim/test1/functionTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    monitors = get_monitors()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\screeninfo\screeninfo.py", line 37, in get_monitors
    raise ScreenInfoError("No enumerators available")
screeninfo.common.ScreenInfoError: No enumerators available
```

I've tried deleting ScreenInfo and reinstalling it, and installing some other
packages such as **pynput** to no success.
Maybe me using the **kivy** library did something?

Comment: what system do you use? Maybe some systems don't have this function.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)